# Problema al poner imagen cuadrada

Tags: html, css

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Hola estoy intentando poner una imagen y que esta vaya de lado a lado de la pantalla pero de altura no me ocupe toda la pagina, solo la mitad. Con el **width:100%** consigo que me quede bien en la entrada pero de altura si le pongo **height:50%** o **height:'x'px** me deforma la calidad de la imagen. Yo lo que quiero por decirlo de alguna manera es que el div de la imagen me ocupe la mitad de la pagina. La imagen podéis colocar cualquiera, la que yo pongo es de 5184x3456.

```css
html{
    overflow: auto;
    
}  #titulo{
   margin-left:400px;
   width: 50%;
   background: white;
   font-size: 4em;
   border-radius: 500px;
   text-align: center;
    
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.contenedor {
  text-align: center;
    
}

.centrado {
  font-size: 3em;
  font-family: 'Fredericka the Great', cursive;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
    top:150px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    
}

.imagen1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto,
  
    
}
.texto1{
font-family: 'Fredericka the Great', cursive;
    color:white;
    font-size:2em;
    margin-top: 90%;
}
#nav{
   float:left;
   width:100%;
   background-color: white;
   margin:0%;
   padding: 0%;
   text-align: center;
   margin-top:20px;
   
}

#nav li{

   float:left;
   display: inline;
   width:25%;
   list-style: none;
   position:relative; 
}

#nav li a{
   color:#666;
   text-decoration:none;
   display:inline;
   font-size:30pt;
    font-family: 'Nanum Pen Script', cursive;

}

#nav li a:hover{
   border:1px black solid;
   color:black;
   border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: green;
    opacity: 0.6;
}

#nav li.parent:hover{
   margin:0px;
   background-color: white;
}


#nav li ul {
 float: none;
   width: 100%;
   padding: 0%;
   display:none;
   background-color: white;
   border-radius: 12px;
    border:1px green;
   position: relative;
   left: -1px;
   top:100%;
   
}

#nav li:hover ul {
   display: block;
    float: none;
}
#nav li li{
   display:block;
    float: none;
       width: 100%;
   margin:0%;
   padding: 0%;
}

#nav li li a{
   display:block;
    float: none;
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>layout</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css_total.css"/>
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Shadows+Into+Light" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fredericka+the+Great" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nanum+Pen+Script" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="contenedor">
  <img src="imagen.jpg" class="imagen1"/>
  <div class="centrado">
      <h4 class="texto1">EL PAGÈS DE RUBÍ</h4>
      </div>
</div>
  <ul id="nav">
        <li class="parent"><a href="#">Inici</a></li>
         <li class="parent"><a href="#">Coneixen's</a></li>
         <li class="parent"><a href="#">Varietats que oferim</a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href="hawaii.html">Fruites</a></li>
               <li><a href="bigbang.html">Verdures</a></li>
               <li><a href="flash.html">Llegums</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li class="parent"><a href="#">Contacta'ns</a></li>
      </ul>
    <p>holaaaaaaa</p>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: La imagen quieres que se vea solo la mitad?

Comment: quiero que se vea la imagen entera, pero solo ocupando la mitad de la pantalla por decirlo de alguna manera.  https://canfeliu.com/carta-2/  si miras esta pagina puedes ver a que me refiero, la imagen se mantiene intacta pero solo ocupa una mitad de la pantalla.

Comment: Ah ya, es fácil de lograr, se hace con un div y un background, quieres que te haga el ejemplo?

Comment: te lo agradecería.

Comment: Hola, yo casi publiqué una pregunta muy similar a esto. Si pudieras poner un ejemplo también te lo agradecería

Answer (score 2):

Se puede lograr con `vh50`. Te dejo un ejemplo:

> vh (viewport-height) = Altura de la ventana gráfica.

```css
.prueba{
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/1400/600);
  background-size: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 50vh;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="prueba">
       
</div>
```

**Actualización:**

Cambia la imagen al `CSS` y en `URL` pones la ruta de tu imagen.

Comment: me sigue saliendo una resolución mala en la foto...

Comment: Si no pongo un height la foto se ve perfecta pero tengo que bajar la barra para terminar de ver la foto, si pongo la opción height ya me deforma la imagen, solo funciona si pongo 100% pero me queda igual que si no pongo nada...

Comment: muestra una captura de cómo te sale. Creo que debe ser la calidad, como bien dices tú, de la resolución de la imagen que estás ocupando

Comment: como inserto capturas/archivos aqui?

Comment: no sé si se puede como comentario, pero puedes editar tu pregunta y subirla al final indicando que usaste el código de @DjCrazy

Comment: ya lo tienes subido

Comment: @winnie actualicé mi respuesta con una variación. Verifica si se ajusta a tus requerimientos.

Comment: Pero en el ccs de imagen pongo lo mismo que tenia puesto en el html, osea el nombre de la foto.jpg si el archivo css esta en la misma carpeta que la foto?

Comment: @winnie es correcto! `background-image: url(imagen.jpg);`

Answer (score 1):

Si deseas usarla como header o baner principal en la pagina tal vez te quede mejor si la utilizas como fondo del div y con este controlar el tamaño (alto y ancho) de lo que quieres visualizar sin alterar el aspecto de la imagen, lo si, tendrías que jugar con el valor "background-position" para lograr mostrar el área que mejor te parezca.

Aunque siempre es recomendable utilizar imágenes dentro de la medida que se va a utilizar a  escala pero siempre respetando su relación de aspecto para evitar que esta se deforme.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui tienes el codigo completo desde 0, lo hice lo mas parecido a el que me pasaste :)

```css
* {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
html {
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
}
body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
.container {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 60%;
 background-color: black;
 background-image: url(https://canfeliu.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/lafotografica_43B9843-e1537380660312.jpg); /* aqui cambias el url por tu imagen y ya */
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-attachment: scroll;
}
.fondonegrotransparente {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.3) /* aqui puedes cambiar la capa transparente negra que hay por encima de la imagen el ".3" seria el "0.3" de "1" puedes ir probando como queda mejor, o directamente borrar esta parte del css si no te sirve */
}
h1 {
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Ejemplo</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="fondonegrotransparente">
<h1>Ejemplo</h1>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Aqui en un codepen.io te dejo lo mismo pero implementado con tu proyecto:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gEVRXy

Comment: Por favor, considera explicar cómo tu respuesta ayuda a resolver el problema. Las respuestas que son básicamente código [se consideran de baja calidad.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: lo que no sé es como linkear mi foto en css, si tengo la foto en la misma carpeta que el css y la imagen se llama lol.jpg como lo tendria que hacer?

Comment: @winnie tienes carpeta raiz (donde se encuentra el index.html) y luego puedes hacer la carpeta "css" y "images", luego para linkear puedes poner para el css: <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/estilo.css"> y para la imagen background-image: url(../images/lol.jpg);

Comment: @JheymanMejia el codigo es muy basico... que es lo que no se entiende?

Comment: Ahora si que se ve bien la calidad de resolución pero me corta la imagen por la mitad osea, me coge la mitad de arriba y me quita la mitad de abajo de la foto...

Comment: Yo lo entiendo, para algunos usuarios puede ser básico, pero si el OP lo pregunta es porque no tiene el conocimiento aún para saber qué fue lo que hiciste, lo mismo pasará con los futuros usuarios que vengan por una consulta.

Comment: @JheymanMejia okay, en cuanto pueda fundamento mi codigo

Comment: @winnie, quieres que se muestre la imagen entera? No es posible... o se repetira  la imagen o se deformara, si quieres puedes hablarme por algun medio para mostrarme mejor lo que quieres lograr y asi poder ayudarte mejor, saludos

Comment: @Patrick Si me interesaría pero por donde, aquí no hay chat en directo creo.

Comment: @Patrick puedo elegir de donde a donde cortar la foto en el caso que me pasaste? porque me corta la foto y me la muestra bien pero el trozo que muestra me lo selecciona solo.

Comment: @winnie puedes usar "background-position" de css, puedes usar top, bottom, right, left, center, etc... Te dejo un link de ejemplos: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp